# PHP, Fatal error: Call to undefined method, why?

Tags: php, oop, class, methods, undefined

I have a simple php structures.

class Ingredient and class Ingredients, i have this code:

```
class Ingredient
{   
   public function objectIsValid()
   {
      return $validate[0];
   }
}



class Ingredients
{
   public $ingObject;
   function __construct(){   $ingObject = new Ingredient();   }

   public function validateData()
   {
      if($this->ingObject->objectIsValid()      /*** THE ERROR  ***/)
    {   echo "OK";}
      else
    {   echo "NOT";}
   } 
}


$Ingridients = new Ingredients();


$Ingridients->validateData();
```

I just can't understand why do i get the error..

any help will be appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function __construct(){   $ingObject = new Ingredient();   }
```

ought to be

```
function __construct(){   $this->ingObject = new Ingredient();   }
```

In the first case you're setting a local variable, not a field, so it remains `null`. Then on the `validateData` you invoke a method on a null variable.

I'm assuming you snipped some code, because your `Ingredient` class doesn't make sense (there's a `$validate` variable there that isn't defined).

Comment: And it would probably be better to transfer $ingObject as an argument in constructor.